# How to resize menu bar

Tags: css, menubar

I want to resize menu bar because the length and font size looks too small.

I tried like below, but still no change...

```
body {
  width:1300px;
  height:800px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-image:url("wood_texture2.jpg");
}

div#menu {
  margin:40px 0 0 95px;
  text-align:left;
  position:absolute;
  font:18px;
  width:900px;
  heigth:200px;
}
```

Comment: that should go to doctype.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible - and if it was, it would be considered by an overwhelming majority of site visitors as "hijacking" their screen: hiding browser chrome (like the back button) would make people feel that they had been trapped, and you'd very likely lose every visitor you got, never to return.

It is possible to open a popup window full screen, however anyone with a popup-blocker wouldn't get to see it, and it is almost as bad as the above scenario.

I would strongly suggest finding another, more user-friendly strategy. Basically, you need to adapt to the user's needs, not adapt their browser window to your design.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
        * { margin:0 auto;
            padding:0;
            }
                html { background:#ffffff; }
                body{
                         width:1600px;
                         height:800px;
                         overflow:auto;
                         background:#ffffff;
                        }
                div#menu {
                                margin:40px 0 0 95px;
                                text-align:center;
                                position:absolute;
                                }
                div#menu span {
                                font-size:22px;
                                padding-left:14px;
                                }
</style>
```